# enable and disable using selectbox change

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I don't know how to enable and disable a text field using select box option.

Maybe I wrote this totally wrong in the code below.
If I did, please tell me correct code.

```
<body>
<table width="500" border="1">
  <form style="text-align:center" id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <tr>
      <th width="32" nowrap="nowrap">Status</th>
      <th width="32" nowrap="nowrap">Runs</th>
      <th width="16" nowrap="nowrap">6</th>
    </tr>
<?php
$('#Status1').change(function(){
var theVal = $('#Status1').val();
switch(theVal){
    case'0':
        $('#Runs1').prop('disabled', true);
        break;
    case'1':
        $('#Runs1').prop('disabled', false);
        break;
    case'2':
        $('#Runs1').prop('disabled', true);
        break;
    }
});
?>
<tr>
 <td align='center'>
   <select id='Status1'><option value='0'>Not Playing</option><option value='1'>Playing</option><option value='2'>Out</option></select></td>
 <td align='center'>
   <input style='font-weight:bold; background:#FFFFFF; text-align:right; color:#000000;' disabled='disabled' name='Runs1' type='text' id='Runs1' size='5' maxlength='5' value='' />    
 </td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you kidding me @PSR, instead of PHP tags, it should be script tags and this whole function should be $(document).ready function.

Comment: Where r u including your JQuery file ???

Comment: Don't downvote the question man, it is just that he/she doesn't know the syntax or code, but he/she tried, and is asking question. This is the place to ask questions. Don't you think?

Comment: friends i am new in php and what i want to do is enable text box on changing select option. if i select "not playing" textfeild will disable and if i select "playing" then textfield will enable for "out" it will disable again

Comment: Cool Shri.. but you are using the jquery code within PHP tags.. that's all the problem.. And I would prefer to use script either before or after the table.. it is not look nice when you have some scripts withing a sequence of html elements nah... Bad code practice also.. You already got lot of answers, so I do not like to post same answer again.. :)

Comment: thanks @FaizulHasan i will keep your suggestion in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for enabling/disabling the #Run1 input box is nested between PHP tags (server side), but this code is written in javascipt (client-side).

```
<body>
<table width="500" border="1">
  <form style="text-align:center" id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <tr>
      <th width="32" nowrap="nowrap">Status</th>
      <th width="32" nowrap="nowrap">Runs</th>
      <th width="16" nowrap="nowrap">6</th>
    </tr>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#Status1').change(function(){
var theVal = $('#Status1').val();
switch(theVal){
    case'0':
        $('#Runs1').prop('disabled', true);
        break;
    case'1':
        $('#Runs1').prop('disabled', false);
        break;
    case'2':
        $('#Runs1').prop('disabled', true);
        break;
    }
});
</script>
<tr>
 <td align='center'>
   <select id='Status1'><option value='0'>Not Playing</option><option value='1'>Playing</option><option value='2'>Out</option></select></td>
 <td align='center'>
   <input style='font-weight:bold; background:#FFFFFF; text-align:right; color:#000000;' disabled='disabled' name='Runs1' type='text' id='Runs1' size='5' maxlength='5' value='' />    
 </td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
```

Comment: Code will work but I would prefer to use the script either before table or after table. Script within some html elements sequence is not look nice. Bad practice..

Comment: @FaizulHasan: The answer only fixed existing code. Your comment is great but might be better on the main question aimed at the person asking the question. It is their code :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `<?php` with `<script>` and `?>` with `</script>.` Rest all the thing is fine.

The code you wrote in php tags is a Jquery code, so it should be under script tags.

Comment: thanks Sankalp Mishra but i want to do it in php is that work in php file also

Comment: yes. even if you save this as .php file with script tags in it, it will work fine . :)

Answer (score 1):

load jquery in your `<head>` and add the javascript there.. not inside `<?php` (php code)

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#Status1').change(function(){
  var theVal = $('#Status1').val();
  switch(theVal){
  case'0':
    $('#Runs1').prop('disabled', true);
    break;
  case'1':
    $('#Runs1').prop('disabled', false);
    break;
  case'2':
    $('#Runs1').prop('disabled', true);
    break;
 }
});
</script>
<body>
....//rest of your code
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not included the jquery file and used  tags instead of  for the javascript code

```
<body>
<table width="500" border="1">
<form style="text-align:center" id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<tr>
  <th width="32" nowrap="nowrap">Status</th>
  <th width="32" nowrap="nowrap">Runs</th>
  <th width="16" nowrap="nowrap">6</th>
</tr>
<script src="../jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#Status1').change(function(){
var theVal = $('#Status1').val();
switch(theVal){
 case'0':
    $('#Runs1').prop('disabled', true);
    break;
 case'1':
    $('#Runs1').prop('disabled', false);
    break;
case'2':
    $('#Runs1').prop('disabled', true);
    break;
   }
});
</script>
<tr>
 <td align='center'>
 <select id='Status1'><option value='0'>Not Playing</option><option value='1'>Playing</option><option value='2'>Out</option></select></td>
<td align='center'>
  <input style='font-weight:bold; background:#FFFFFF; text-align:right; color:#000000;' disabled='disabled' name='Runs1' type='text' id='Runs1' size='5' maxlength='5' value='' />    
</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like:

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <table width="500" border="1">
      <form style="text-align:center" id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
        <tr>
            <th width="32" nowrap="nowrap">Status</th>
            <th width="32" nowrap="nowrap">Runs</th>
            <th width="16" nowrap="nowrap">6</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align='center'>
            <select id='Status1'><option value='0'>Not Playing</option><option value='1'>Playing</option><option value='2'>Out</option></select></td>
            <td align='center'>
            <input style='font-weight:bold; background:#FFFFFF; text-align:right; color:#000000;' disabled='disabled' name='Runs1' type='text' id='Runs1' size='5' maxlength='5' value='' />    
            </td>
        </tr>
    </form>
    </table>
</body>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Status1').change(function(){
        var theVal = $('#Status1').val();
        switch(theVal){
            case'0':
                $('#Runs1').prop('disabled', true);
                break;
            case'1':
                $('#Runs1').prop('disabled', false);
                break;
            case'2':
                $('#Runs1').prop('disabled', true);
                break;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

But first check you have added a `jquery library file` in the `head section`.

Answer (score 0):

friends this is solution of my question with the help of you people thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.min.js"></script>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Status1').change(function(){
        var theVal = $('#Status1').val();
        switch(theVal){
            case'0':
                $('#Runs1').prop('disabled', true);
                break;
            case'1':
                $('#Runs1').prop('disabled', false);
                break;
            case'2':
                $('#Runs1').prop('disabled', true);
                break;
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="500" border="1">
      <form style="text-align:center" id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
        <tr>
            <th width="32" nowrap="nowrap">Status</th>
            <th width="32" nowrap="nowrap">Runs</th>
            <th width="16" nowrap="nowrap">6</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align='center'>
            <select id='Status1'><option value='0'>Not Playing</option><option value='1'>Playing</option><option value='2'>Out</option></select></td>
            <td align='center'>
            <input style='font-weight:bold; background:#FFFFFF; text-align:right; color:#000000;' disabled='disabled' name='Runs1' type='text' id='Runs1' size='5' maxlength='5' value='' />    
            </td>
        </tr>
    </form>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```